# Using generic types in constructor call without using types in the parameters

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

Is it possible to use generics in a constructor call without using the types in the parameters like that, or is there another way of doing this?

```
type PersonProps = {
  name: string,
}

class Model<P> {
  label: string;

  constructor(label: string) {
    this.label = label;
  }

  create(props: P): Promise<any> { ... }
}

const Person = new Model<PersonProps>('Person');
```

EDIT:

I get the following flow errors in Visual Studio Code and no autocomplete results at all:

```
test.js:11
11: const Person = new Model<PersonProps>('Person');
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ boolean. This type cannot be compared to
11: const Person = new Model<PersonProps>('Person');
                                          ^^^^^^^^ string

test.js:11
11: const Person = new Model<PersonProps>('Person');
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^ PersonProps. type referenced from value position
  5: type PersonProps = {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^ type PersonProps
```

Comment: From the [tag:flow]: *"This is a meta tag and should not be used. See the wiki for more information."* Did you mean [tag:flowtype]?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks I added the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and in fact cannot) specify the type parameter there:

```
const Person = new Model('Person');
```

If you would like to specify the full type, with the type parameter, for the `Person` variable, you can add a type annotation:

```
const Person: Model<PersonProps> = new Model('Person');
```

The errors you are seeing are due to the fact that the `<` and `>` characters parse as "less than" and "greater than" in that context.

Comment: But otherwise I would not get autocomplete results if I call the create method.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can annotate Person: `const Person: Model<PersonProps> = new Model('Person');`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean by annotate the Person? EDIT: Thanks, give me a second and I'll try that ;)

Comment: I hit enter before I meant to. I edited the comment with a line of code.

Comment: Thanks it works :) Could you edit your answer so I can accept it as the answer?